# HTML trying to use javascript codes as text

Tags: html

I want to use javascript as a text for an example.
Here is the following code:

```
<p>
    <!-- XSS Example 1 -->                      
    <h5> Here you can see how the XSS works <h5>
    <img src="example/xssexample1.jpg" alt="XSS Example 1">
    <br><br>
    <!-- ************************************************************************************************** -->
    <!-- XSS Example 2 -->      
    <h5> Example of injecting malicious JavaScript: <h5>
    <img src="example/xssexample2.jpg" alt="XSS Example 2">
    <br><br>
    Now the attacker can craft a URL in the following format and send it to the victim:
    <br><br>
    http://www.test-attack.com/index.php?name=myuser <script>alert(‘hacked’)</script>
    When the victim loads the URL shown above into the browser, he will see an alert box with the text "hacked". 
    Even though this specific example doesn’t cause any damage besides the annoying "hacked" pop-up,
    it’s clear how an attacker can use this simple and straightforward method to exploit websites and applications.                             
</p>
```

So i want to have `http://www.test-attack.com/index.php?name=myuser <script>alert(‘hacked’)</script>` as text but all you can see is the url without the JavaScript code.

I have jquery loaded, so i wanted to ask is it possible to make it visible ?

Comment: You want it to show "http://www.test-attack.com/index.php?name=myuser <script>alert(‘hacked’)</script>" in the text, but instead it shows "http://www.test-attack.com/index.php?name=myuser" and probably comes with an alert box, is that the problem?

Comment: Yes , the javascript will be executed and i don't know how to fix it .

Comment: Escape the tags. `<` becomes `&gt;` and `>` becomes `&lt;`

Comment: In that case, nbkhope has the correct answer. 
Since you are apparently learning about XSS, this is moreover a nice practical example

Answer (score 1):

You have to escape the `<` and `>` for the tags so that they are interpreter as literal characters instead of html tags.

The HTML code for `<` is `&lt;` and for `>` is `&gt;` (meaning less than and greater than, respectively).

So you have to write as such:

```
&lt;script&gt;alert(‘hacked’)&lt;/script&gt;
```

[See this JSFiddle example.](https://jsfiddle.net/ww8Lbppr/1/)